# AngularJS: "Expand" controller in DOM (when you can't modify entire page HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, wordpress

I'm working with AngularJS in Wordpress using shortcode to insert HTML into the post body.

The problem is that I can only add my app and controller attributes within the body of the post content:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="dynamic-content" ng-app="dynamicContent" ng-controller="dynamicContent as p">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
</div>
```

Let's say I want my app to also control an area in the sidebar. I'm forced to modify some core files so I can get `ng-app` and `ng-controller` higher in the DOM.

This is a hassle, because inserting Angular apps easily into posts (without modifying more of the page code) is a prerogative.

I've tried adding the `ng-app` and `ng-controller` attributes to the page `body` with jQuery, but of course this doesn't work.

Aside from delaying Angular, inserting these attributes with jQuery, and then letting Angular run once the attributes are in place, is there any way I can "expand" my controller into other parts of the DOM tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [manual application bootstrap method](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization), it allows to bind the angular application to the DOM without using the `ng-app`:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myId"), ['myApp']);` to manually attach an app to a given DOM element. This is useful for when you cannot edit the HTML, or if you have more than one ng-app on a given page.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers from Boris Serebrov and mhodges.

Incidentally, I stumbled upon another, less elegant solution.

If a `div` loads with `ng-controller` as an ancestor and I then move this `div` to another part of the DOM using jQuery (i.e. the `ng-controller` is no longer an ancestor), the app still works as if the `div` was still in its original position.